# Prism DLL Not Built Against the Silverlight Runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, prism, silverlight-5.0

I am using Prism 4.1 and Visual Studio 2010 in my WPF projects and everything is ok, but once I try to add a reference to "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll" in a Silverlight 5 project, the dll doesn't appear in the .net list of assmblies, so I browse to the dll location manually, then the following message appears:

> You can't add a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll as it was
>   not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will
>   only work with Silverlight assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the proper assemblies which are compiled for **Silverlight** instead of **WPF**.

Notice that the Prism source code has 3 folders inside the **Bin** folder: "***Desktop***"; "***Phone***"; and "***Silverlight***".

Therefore, using the .dll assemblies from the **Silverlight** folder would solve your issue.

I hope this helped you,

Regards.

Comment: Actually I have used the one in "Silverlight" directory but that didn't work.
Re-installing the silverlight SDK has solved the problem, which's not so good as I couldn't know the real reason of the problem.